# use items in select query that don't include in Group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I am using EF6 to develop an application that uses a huge data,so in one of my query

```
his = db.HISTORies.ToList();
            front = db.Fronts.ToList();
            warehouses = db.Warehouses.ToList();
            //------
            var q =
                his.GroupBy(j => new { j.Line_Number_PGZ, j.MAT_0_PG,j.JOINT_NO_PGZ }).ToList().Select(m => new gridView()
                {
                    JointNumber = m.Key.JOINT_NO_PGZ,
                    material0 = m.Key.MAT_0_PGZ,material0Name =his.Where(i=>i.MAT_0_PGZ==m.Key.MAT_0_PGZ).First().Code_0_Object_PGZ,
                    line = m.Key.Line_Number_PGZ
                }).OrderByDescending(i => i.material0Need).ToList();
```

As you can see i fetch all my database to my application .so in my query i grouped my data based on 2 columns ,but my problem is the `his` has a lot of records so in this line

```
his.Where(i=>i.MAT_0_PGZ==m.Key.MAT_0_PGZ).First().Code_0_Object_PGZ
```

I again search an items in this table and this line makes my application to be so slow how can fix this query?

The `Code_0_Object_PGZ` is in `his` list but it can be accessed in the select statement !!!

I want to know how can i access `Code_0_Object_PGZ` without include it in groupby ?

best regards

Comment: Why do you load the whole database to memory? SQL storage is much better in this kind of operations than regular LINQ methods. Use LINQ to Entities until you have all the required information and only then load the results into memory.

Comment: Because i need all information so i have to load all of them

Comment: That's OK, but all the operations you perform, such as GroupBy and Where are much more efficient when they are performed by SQL. Try and see the difference. You can load the results prepared by SQL.